# How to run kafka on different machines

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat

From last 10 days i am trying to set Kafka on different machine:

1. Server32
2. Server56

Below are the list of task which i have done so far

- Configured Zookeeper and started on both server  with

> server.1=Server32_IP:2888:3888
>
> server.2=Server56_IP:2888:3888

- I also changed server and server-1 properties as below

> broker.id=0   port=9092   log.dir=/tmp/kafka0-logs
>   host.name=Server32
>   zookeeper.connect=Server32_IP:9092,Server56_IP:9062

& server-1

> broker.id=1   port=9062   log.dir=/tmp/kafka1-logs
>   host.name=Server56
>   zookeeper.connect=Server32_IP:9092,Server56_IP:9062

Server.property i ran in Server32
Server-1.property i ran in Server56

> The Problem is : when i start producer in both the servers and if i try to consume from any one then it is working BUT
>   **When i stop any one server then another one is not able to send the details**

Please help me in explaining the process

Comment: Did you check the Kafka broker log to see if any errors or additional information was logged at the time? What was the replication factor setting for the topic created?

Comment: Check the logs of your Kafka brokers to be able to have more information on your problem

Comment: @wFateem: factor is 1

Comment: @Imba: There is no logs...but it is not receiving anything then

Comment: When you put down a broker, how is described the topic :
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper HOST:2181 --topic TOPIC`

Comment: When i ^C the terminal of Server56 then after running the command it shows error: cannot connect to the IP
and if i check for Server32 then nothing happens only command enter.

Comment: I Followed this link https://cuongba.com/installing-apache-kafka-multi-nodes-and-multi-brokers-on-ubuntu/

Comment: For the command I gave you, you don't have to run it in a broker terminal, but in a new terminal in your Kafka folder. It will request Zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

Running 2 zookeepers is not fault tolerant. If one of the zookeepers is stopped, then the system will not work. Unlike Kafka brokers, zookeeper needs a quorum (or majority) of the configured nodes in order to work. This is why zookeeper is typically deployed with an odd number of instances (nodes). Since 1 of 2 nodes is not a majority it really is no better than running a single zookeeper. You need at least 3 zookeepers to tolerate a failure because 2 of 3 is a majority so the system will stay up.

Kafka is different so you can have any number of Kafka brokers and if they are configured correctly and you create your topics with a replication factor of 2 or greater, then the Kafka cluster can continue if you take any one of the broker nodes down , even if it's just 1 of 2.

Comment: it is not working even when i am having replication factor of 3. If any broker goes down other two stopped working.

Comment: I’m surprised you’re still struggling with this 4 years later. I think it might be difficult to understand what’s going on in your environment without you providing more information. So now you have three brokers and your topic has a replication factor of three? Can you run the following command and show us the output of what your topic looks like before and again after you stop your broker(s) please? 

kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ZHOST:2181 --describe

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of information missing here like the Kafka version and whether or not you're using the new consumer APIs or the old APIs. I'm assuming you're probably using a new version of Kafka like 0.10.x along with the new client APIs. In the new version of the client APIs the log data is stored on the Kafka brokers and not Zookeeper as in the older versions. I think your issue here is that you created your topics with a replication factor of 1 and coincidently the Kafka broker server you shutdown was hosting the only replica, so you won't be able to produce or consume messages. You can confirm the health of your topics by running the command:

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ZHOST:2181 --describe
```

You might want to increase the replication factor to 2. That way you might be able to get away with one broker failing. Ideally you would have 3 or more Kafka Broker servers with a replication factor of 2 or higher (obviously not more than the number of brokers in your cluster). Refer to the link below:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor

> For a topic with replication factor N, we will tolerate up to N-1 server >failures without losing any records committed to the log."

Comment: i tried it with more than 2 replication factor but facing same problem.